# Can I copy multiple directories into a single directory with a single command?

Tags: command-line, directory, file-copy, recursive

I have used photorec to recover data from a HDD and now have many directories   `/home/ray/recup_dir.1`, to `/home/ray/recup-dir.598` taking up valuable space in my Home directory.

I want to copy them into another directory `/media/ray/"Seagate Expansion Drive"/RecupsA`

How do I do this with one command?

Comment: What is wrong with `cp`? Like `cp -r /home/ray/recup_dir.{1..598} "/media/ray/Seagate Expansion Drive"/RecupsA"`. Or maybe you want rather to move them, not copy?

Answer (score 3):

The first solution I thought of is rsync. Exclude everything. Include directories matching a pattern.  I'll admit that it feels strange to copy information to the same host using rsync. Usually it it used to copy to a remote computer. However I see no reason why you could not just copy to localhost.

```
rsync -ravz --include '/home/ray/recup_dir.*' --exclude '*' user@localhost
```

Explanation of ravz:

```
-r recursive copy
-v verbose
-a : archive mode. Preserves symbolic links, file permissions, user & group ownerships,  timestamps
-z : compress file data
```

---

A second option is to cheat and type `mc`. This will start [midnight commander](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midnight_Commander), allowing you to select multiple directories and then copy them.

---

Third option: find.

```
find /home/ray/recup_dir.\*  -exec cp {} /media/ray/"Seagate Expansion Drive"/RecupsA \;
```

---

Fourth option: Use the shell. Go to /home/ray/ and then

```
for a in recup* ; do cp -r $a /media/ray/"Seagate Expansion Drive"/RecupsA; done
```

Answer (score 2):

Use standard `cp` with `r`ecursive option:

```
cp -r /home/ray/recup_dir.{1..598} "/media/ray/Seagate Expansion Drive/RecupsA"
```

But I have a feeling that you rather want to move them, in such case:

```
mv /home/ray/recup_dir.{1..598} "/media/ray/Seagate Expansion Drive/RecupsA"
```

Both those commands treat only last argument as *destination*, and all previous ones as *sources* (files or directories).